# Change a "list" value depending on selected element of another "list"

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, attr

I have several datalists that need to be added to an input depending on a selected value from another datalist. Specifically I have dog breeds and cat breeds that I need to show if the user either selected pet type as "Dog" or "Cat":

```
<datalist id="animalTypes">
  <option value="Dog">
  <option value="Cat">
  <option value="Iguana">
  <option value="Snake">
  <option value="Hamster">
  </datalist>

  <datalist id="defaultbreedvar">
  <option value="Select a type">
  </datalist>

  <datalist id="dogvar">
  <option value="Pug">
  <option value="Labrador">
  <option value="Huskee">
  <option value="Golden Retreiver">
  <option value="Street dog">
  </datalist>

  <datalist id="catvar">
  <option value="Angora">
  <option value="Persian">
  <option value="Bombay">
  <option value="Shorthair">
  <option value="Street dog">
  </datalist>
```

Inside the form tag, the HTML looks like this:

```
<table>
          <tr>
            <td>Pet Type</td>
            <td><input  class="dropDown" name="petType" id="petType" list="animalTypes"  ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Pet Type Variation</td>
            <td><input class="dropDown" name="petSubType" id="petSubType"  list="defaultbreedvar"  ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Pet Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="petName" id="petName"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

and the jquery code that selects which data list is shown looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function selectPetBreed()
    {
        var petType = $("#petType").attr("value");
        if (petType == "Dog"){
            $("#petSubType").attr("list","dogvar");
        };
        if (petType == "Cat"){
            $("#petSubType").attr("list","catvar");
        }

    };
    $(document).on("change, keyup", "#petType", selectPetBreed);
});
```

but this doesn't change my list shown, It's always the default breed datalist hardcoded. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/d3aynegv/)

change

```
$(document).on("change, keyup", "#petType", selectPetBreed);
```

to

```
$('input').bind("change", selectPetBreed);
```

and change

```
var petType = $("#petType").attr("value");
```

to

```
var petType = ("#petType").val();
```